# Summarize Loop Results in Pandas Table

Tags: python, pandas, loops, linear-regression

I got the code that downloads tickers and runs the linear regression for each stock in the downloaded list.  I am stuck on the last step:  showing Prediction & Residual values for each stock, for the last date in the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
from sklearn import linear_model

tickers = ['EXPE','MSFT']

data = yf.download(tickers, start="2012-04-03", end="2017-07-07")['Close']
data = data.reset_index()
data = data.dropna()

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Date"])
df["Date"]=df["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.toordinal())

for ticker in tickers:
   data[ticker] = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = [ticker])
   X = df
   y = data[ticker]
   lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
   model = lm.fit(X,y)
   predictions = lm.predict(X)
   residuals = y-lm.predict(X)
   print (predictions[-1:])
   print(residuals[-1:])
```

The current output looks like this:

```
[136.28856636]
1323    13.491432
Name: EXPE, dtype: float64
[64.19943648]
1323    5.260563
Name: MSFT, dtype: float64
```

But I would like it to show like this (as pandas table):

```
        Predictions Residuals
EXPE    136.29      13.49
MSFT    64.20       5.26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this where you store values in a list:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
from sklearn import linear_model

tickers = ['EXPE','MSFT']

data = yf.download(tickers, start="2012-04-03", end="2017-07-07")['Close']
data = data.reset_index()
data = data.dropna()

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Date"])
df["Date"]=df["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.toordinal())

predictions_output = []
residuals_output = []

for ticker in tickers:
    data[ticker] = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = [ticker])
    X = df
    y = data[ticker]
    lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    model = lm.fit(X,y)
    predictions = lm.predict(X)
    residuals = y-lm.predict(X)
    predictions_output.append(float(predictions[-1:]))
    residuals_output.append(float(residuals[-1:]))


expectation_df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(predictions_output, residuals_output)), 
               columns =['Predictions', 'Residuals']).set_index([tickers])
print(expectation_df)
```

with the output being:

```
      Predictions  Residuals
EXPE   136.288566  13.491432
MSFT    64.199436   5.260563
```

**EDIT**: I went too quickly and looked back and realized `tickers` was already defined, so you can use that to set your index here and lose the `Tickers` index heading to match your desired output.

Also if you want those values rounded, you can just append these two lines in your loop:

```
predictions_output.append(round(float(predictions[-1:]), 2))
residuals_output.append(round(float(residuals[-1:]), 2))
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you

Comment: @user10425666 If this works, please consider accepting the answer, thanks!

Comment: I just did.  Does it show as accepted.  Sorry, for some reason it did not work yesterday